# Function squaring 2-d array python

Tags: python, list

I have a function that takes in any 2-d array and return a 2-d array (the same format as the array being implemented) but the values are squared. 
i.e `[[1,2],[3,4]]` -----> `[[1,4],[9,16]]`

my code so far:

```
m0 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
empty_list = []
for x in m0:
   for i in x:
     empyt_list.append(x**2)
```

This gives me a 1-d array but how would i return a 2-d array as the imputed value?

Comment: Is the 2d list (Python has no builtin arrays) rectangular (have all sublists the same length)?

Answer (score 1):

## Working with an outer list

The point is that you will need an extra list outside to store the columns. So we can introduce temporary lists we build up and add as `rows`:

```
m0 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
result = []
for sublist in m0:
    row = []
    for item in sublist:
        row.append(item**2)
    result.append(row)
```

Notice that we here iterate over the `item`s of the `sublist`.

## Using list comprehension

We can however write this more elegantly with list comprehension

```
result = [[x*x for x in sublist] for sublist in m0]
```

> **Note**: if you have to square a number `x`, it is usually more efficient to use `x * x`, then to write `x ** 2`.

## Using `numpy` (for rectangular lists)

In case the list is rectangular (all sublists have the *same* length), we can use numpy instead:

```
from numpy import array

a0 = array(m0)
result = a0 ** 2
```

Comment: From a quick unscientific `%timeit` test, while the listcomp takes almost 3x as long with `x**2` than `x*x`, the numpy version takes about 80% as long.  (Also, they're both so fast that the OP is unlikely to care about the difference unless he's doing this huge numbers of times.)

Comment: @abarnert: I think you are correct about `numpy`: since a power can be done very *locally*, there is a boost since it only has to load *one* array into memory. But for numbers, `x * x` is indeed approximately twice as fast.

Comment: Actually, from another quick test, the numpy results are totally different for my Mac 3.6, Mac 2.7, cointainer-linux 3.5, and container-linux 2.7, although they're always pretty close either way, so… the real moral is probably that if the 20% difference ever matters, you probably need to benchmark it with your real target system and real data rather than trust a comment by Some Guy on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a recursive function to handle *any* depth of nested lists:

```
def SquareList(L):
    if type(L) is list:
        return [SquareList(x) for x in L]
    else:
        return L**2
```

Example:

```
 > print(SquareList([1,[3],[2,[3]],4]))
 [1, [9], [4, [9]], 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this by a list comprehension:

```
empty_list = [[m0[i][j]**2 for j in range(len(m0[i]))] for i in range(len(m0))]
```

Or like your Codestyle:

```
empty_list = m0

for i in range(len(m0)):
    for j in range(len(m0[i])):
        empty_list[i][j] = m0[i][j] ** 2
```

Your problem is that you never created a 2D-list and you just append the values on the created 1D-list.

Comment: I think you forgot to cose a few brackets (in both the first and second code sample).

Comment: Why use indices instead of just iterating the contents in your listcomp? It'll be a lot harder to get the parens wrong (which is a real issue, considering that you got them wrong…), and a lot more readable.

Comment: @abarnert: and more efficient as well: since `range(..)` is an iterable as well, so it only results in *more* indirection. Furthermore some collections (like `set`s and `dict`s) are iterable but not indexable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Definitely, not to mention that you can turn it into a genexpr and use it lazily as part of an iterator-transforming pipeline… But I figured for the OP and the answer writer, simpler and easier to get right was a better headline.